# Laravel - new guard issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, fortify

I am using Laravel/Fortify to manage my authentication. I have created a new guard to allow employees to log in.

Employee credentials now work but whenever I tried and retrieve the authenticated employees details via `{{ Auth::user() }}` it returns null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Auth::guard('your_guard_name')->user()

Answer (score 0):

1. `composer require laravel/fortify`
2. `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\\Fortify\\FortifyServiceProvider"`
3. `php artisan migrate`

Open `config/app.php and` register Fortify service provider:

```
App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
```

Next, open `config/fortify.php` and update your features array as follow:

```
'features' => [
    Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
],
```

Now we need to tell Fortify where is our auth views.

Open `app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php` and in the boot method add:

```
Fortify::loginView(function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Fortify::registerView(function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});

Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function () {
    return view('auth.forgot-password');
});

Fortify::resetPasswordView(function () {
    return view('auth.reset-password');
});
```

**Protect your pages**

Now we need to protect our routes, open routes/web.php and use auth middleware, like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware(['auth']);
```